# How to cancel FutureResult execution

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, concurrency

I'm using 3rd Party concurrency library ported to 1.4 which can be downloaded from here 
http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2004-September/001035.html

```
  Executor executor = new PooledExecutor.....
  FutureResult futureImage = new FutureResult();
   Runnable command = futureImage.setter(new Callable() {
          public Object call() { //doSomething }
       });
       executor.execute(command);
```

I need to cancel `FutureResult` or stop execution of current `Runnable`.

If I were using `Future<P>` from java 1.5, I would call cancel() method, but how can I do it here?

Answer (score 1):

Implement Cancel yourself, for example by providing a `cancelled` variable which you check during execution of your future.

Comment: Sorry but I've not got your idea, where shoul I add cancelled variable?